# Multiplayer call to Telegram bot

Tags: python, bots, imap, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm writing a telegram-bot. It checks the email box(common to all), and if it finds the set parameters then returns some information to the user and delete this email that contains this parameters. So the problem is this: when I call this bot alone, everything's allright, but if I cal it from several accounts at the same time, it doesn't work correctly. It either doesn't send the information, or sends it incorrectly. It sends the info which belongs to other user. I can't solve this? Can anybody advise me somethin? Sorry for my Ruslish)))

Comment: HI there, can you post your code?

Comment: You can try to use some mechanism that will make sure that the bot does not work in parallel, but it will process one user after another in sequence. Without telling us more details about your solution and environment, we nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: I can't make this, I don't know how to do it)

Comment: It writes me Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Comment: You can read [this link](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#user) and find out how you can filter users by their ids. if (userID = 1) it's AlexSN else it's [@GameO7er](https://t.me/GameO7er) . if you need anyhelp contact me on Telegram.